# Using contains() with firebase rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, contains

I am trying to set a custom rule in Firestore using the following documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#containssubstring

I'm using the custom claims for this.

What works:

```
match /calendar/{calendar} {
    allow read: if request.auth.token.customData == "calendar-read,calendar-write";
}
```

What doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
match /calendar/{calendar} {
    allow read: if request.auth.token.customData.contains("calendar-read");
}
```

This will give me: "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions"

Comment: You are mixing up the security rules for the Realtime Database (cf. the link in your question) and for Firestore (`match /calendar/{calendar}`). You need to give more detail on how you set the Custom Claims in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using Firestore, you should use the API documentation for [Firestore String](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String), not Realtime Database String.  You will see that there is no method called "contains" for Firestore strings.

If you want to check if there is a substring contained within a string, you should use [matches()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches) instead, and provide a regular expression to match with.

```
allow read: if request.auth.token.customData.matches(".*calendar-read.*");
```

The above should return true if `request.auth.token.customData` contains the string "calendar-read" anywhere within it.

If you are using a comma-separated list of values, consider instead using [split()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#split) and [list.hasAny()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny) to be more clear.